# Who came up with the terms "act utilitarianism" and "rule utilitarianism"?

Tags: reference-request, history-of-philosophy, terminology, utilitarianism

I see plenty on the distinction itself, and plenty about the history of people developing views that seem to use the distinction (though they don't use these specific terms), but I can't find who actually first used these exact terms we talk about so much. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both terms were first used by Richard Brandt in 1959 in his book *Ethical Theory*.